# Can I check this in ArchUnit

Tags: archunit

I have a a proverbial Log4J logger.

```
Logger logger = new Logger(MyClass.class);
```

Can I check that the correct filed is pass to the Logger?

Comment: Do I understand this right, if `logger` is defined in `MyClass` you want to verify that it's `new Logger(MyClass.class)`, and if it's defined in `OtherClass` it should be `new Logger(OtherClass.class)`?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible. I tried to create a rule declaring `noClasses().should().accessTargetWhere(new LoggerCreationPredicate())` with `LoggerCreationPredicate` checking the owner and target of the provided `JavaAccess`. It is pretty easy to detect logger creation calls and retrieve the class name of such a place. However, I got stuck determining the parameter value handed over to the constructor of `Logger`. While it is possible to retrieve the parameter type, I am unsure if and how to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Not with Log4j 1 by itself. With Log4j 2 you could just do:

```
Logger logger = new LogManager.getLogger();
```

Or you could use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/log) and just use @Log4j (or @Log4j2) at the beginning of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: ArchUnit does not analzye method call parameter values, see also [#596](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/596).

Comment: For this very concrete case it might be possible to check if there is a constructor call `new Logger(..)` and a `ReferencedClassObject` to a class other than `MyClass.class` with the same line number. Which is only a heuristic of course, but maybe good enough.